# How to set text alignment for textField with help of expression?

Tags: jasper-reports

How to change text alignment for textField using parameter value?

Answer (score 1):

The [net.sf.jasperreports.style.hTextAlign](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/config.reference.html#net.sf.jasperreports.style.hTextAlign) property can be used for solving this task. This property can be applied for report's element, such as *textField*.

### Example

I used *One Empty Record* data adapter at Studio for running/building the report.

#### Report template

The parameter with name ***alignment*** is using for setting horizontal text alignment.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Text alignment example" pageWidth="200" pageHeight="200" columnWidth="200" leftMargin="0" rightMargin="0" topMargin="0" bottomMargin="0">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="One Empty Record"/>
    <parameter name="alignment" class="java.lang.String">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["Right"]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <title>
        <band height="40" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="0" y="10" width="200" height="30">
                    <propertyExpression name="net.sf.jasperreports.style.hTextAlign"><![CDATA[$P{alignment}]]></propertyExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Some text"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </title>
</jasperReport>
```

Expression for property is set via *propertyExpression*:

```
<propertyExpression name="net.sf.jasperreports.style.hTextAlign"><![CDATA[$P{alignment}]]></propertyExpression>
```

#### Output result

The output result at *JSS*

[image: The generated report via preview at JSS]

Comment: What excatly is not working? It is a working example

Comment: Yes its working now. actually my report version problem it should be resolved. i have one more question how can i apply expression on alignment parameter. my expression is :- $P{alignment}.equals("c") ? "Right" : "Left"